# Mounting grinding wheels on a threaded rod

Tags: applied-mechanics

I'm trying to mount a set of 6" grinding wheels on an M12 threaded rod.  The problem I have is keeping them perpendicular to the rod so that they don't wobble when they turn.

The wheels have a 1" bore, with two adaptor rings inside and an 5/8" M12 bushing inside those that sits on the threaded rod.  There is absolutely no play between the wheel, the adaptors rings, and the bushing.

There are flanges (with a ~40mm thread) either side of each grinding wheel, but these are not enough to hold it perpendicular to the rod.  In fact, when I tighen the flanges, they no longer sit parallel to the rod, but at a slight angle and the wheel wobbles all over the place.  The only place there is play is between the threaded rod and the flanges and bushing.

Is there anything that can be done to reduce the play?  Or some other way of keeping the wheels perpendicular to the rod?  Or was using a threaded rod for this a bad idea from the start?

Picture of my proof-of-concept build below:

[image: Proof of concept build]

Comment: Last statement is true.

Comment: Can you provide a sketch or drawing showing the assembly and application?

Comment: why are you using flanges with ar 40mm thread on a 12mm threaded rod?

Comment: @Jasen I wasn't clear -- 40mm is the length of the flange, it's an M12 thread.

Comment: @SolarMike I'm gradually coming to the same conclusion.  Annoying because I'm so invested in this design, but I'll investigate other options.

Comment: @r13 Added a picture.

Comment: Take that rod in your hands and see how much you can bend it - it flexes easily with little force. Your design needs a larger diameter shaft.

Comment: It is correct, the rod seems too flexible. Also, placing nuts and lock washers directly on both sides of the wheel can help.

Comment: maybe the tube part of the flange is supposed to go inside the grinding wheel